# Facebook app add to profile

Tags: tabs, addition, profile, facebook-iframe

I want to include add to profile or add to timeline code in my facebook application using iframe. FBML had an easy way to do this. Doesn't seem so for iframe.

Comment: You can't add tab applications to Profile pages, only to Pages.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Add to Profile' and 'Add to Timeline' plugins are being removed by Facebook soon. See the developer road map: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/. Also, remember that FBML support is being removed in June / July.

If the user connects to your application, then your app will be added to their timeline providing the user adds the box manually to their profile. You cannot add custom apps to the user's profile anymore, you can only publish stories (using `publish_stream`) or publish actions (using `publish_actions`).